# unable to write to Firestore after update(Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm unable to write to `firestore`. I think this might have something to do with updating my packages in `pubspec.yaml` but I couldn't be sure. The method I have for writing to `firestore`

```
void onSendMessage(String content, int type) {
    // type: 0 = text, 1 = image, 2 = sticker
    if (content.trim() != '') {
      textEditingController.clear();

      var documentReference = Firestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .document(groupChatId)
          .collection(groupChatId)
          .document(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());
      print(groupChatId);

      Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        await transaction.set(
          documentReference,
          {
            'idFrom': id,
            'idTo': peerId,
            'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
            'content': content,
            'type': type
          },
        );
      });
      listScrollController.animateTo(0.0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeOut);

    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Nothing to send');
    }
  }
```

I've checked all the fields in the `runTransaction` function and they are all containing the values that they should. The problem seems to me is that the `set` method for some reason is not writing the data to `firestore`.

The onSendMessage is called here in my code

```
Material(
            child: new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
                onPressed: () => onSendMessage(textEditingController.text, 0),
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
```

Basically I want to grab the text from a Textfield and send this to `firestore`

There has been **A breaking change** with firestore for version [`0.12.0`](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-changelog-tab-) but I don't think this should effect my code. Also don't have any error logs
**How would I check that I'm getting a Firestore instance** I think this might be the root of thew problem

Comment: Is there a specific reason, why you are using a transaction?